# vboxdrv: module verification failed

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 20.04, boinc

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04 (with current updates) and have the boinc-virtualbox (7.16.6+dfsg-1) package installed via Synaptic from the Ubuntu Software repository.

And I get this message every time I boot the machine:

```
vboxdrv: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

The module still seems to load, but I'd like to eliminate the error message that appears on my screen.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Comment: seems the bug has been there since Ubuntu 16.04. I can confirm the same in Kubuntu 21.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1618346